# What does decoupling two classes at the interface level mean?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, decoupling

Lets say we have  class A in package A and class B in package B . If object of class A has reference to class B, then the two classes are said to have coupling between them.

To address the coupling, it is recommended to define an interface in package A which is implemented by class in package B. Then object of class A can refer to interface in package A . This is often an example in "inversion of dependency".

Is this the example of "decoupling two classes at the interface level". If yes, how does it remove the coupling between classes and retain the same functionality when two classes were coupled?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let us create a fictive example of two classes `A` and `B`.

Class `A` in package `packageA`:

```
package packageA;

import packageB.B;

public class A {
    private B myB;
    
    public A() {
        this.myB = new B();
    }
    
    public void doSomethingThatUsesB() {
        System.out.println("Doing things with myB");
        this.myB.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Class `B` in package `packageB`:

```
package packageB;

public class B {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("B did something.");
    }
}
```

As we see, `A` depends on `B`. Without `B`, `A` cannot be used. We say that `A` is tightly coupled to `B`. What if we want to replace `B` in the future by a `BetterB`? For this, we create an Interface `Inter` within `packageA`:

```
package packageA;

public interface Inter {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

To utilize this interface, we

- `import packageA.Inter;` and let `B implements Inter` in `B` and
- Replace all occurences of `B` within `A` with `Inter`.

The result is this modified version of `A`:

```
package packageA;

public class A {
    private Inter myInter;
    
    public A() {
        this.myInter = ???; // What to do here?
    }
    
    public void doSomethingThatUsesInter() {
        System.out.println("Doing things with myInter");
        this.myInter.doSomething();
    }
}
```

We can see already that the dependency from `A` to `B` is gone: the `import packageB.B;` is no longer needed. There is just one problem: we cannot instantiate an instance of an interface. But [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) comes to the rescue: instead of instantiating something of type `Inter` within `A`'s constructor, the constructor will demand something that `implements Inter` as parameter:

```
package packageA;

public class A {
    private Inter myInter;
    
    public A(Inter myInter) {
        this.myInter = myInter;
    }
    
    public void doSomethingThatUsesInter() {
        System.out.println("Doing things with myInter");
        this.myInter.doSomething();
    }
}
```

With this approach we can now change the concrete implementation of `Inter` within `A` at will. Suppose we write a new class `BetterB`:

```
package packageB;

import packageA.Inter;

public class BetterB implements Inter {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("BetterB did something.");
    }
}
```

Now we can instantiante `A`s with different `Inter`-implementations:

```
Inter b = new B();
A aWithB = new A(b);
aWithB.doSomethingThatUsesInter();

Inter betterB = new BetterB();
A aWithBetterB = new A(betterB);
aWithBetterB.doSomethingThatUsesInter();
```

And we did not have to change anything within `A`. The code is now decoupled and we can change the concrete implementation of `Inter` at will, as long as the contract(s) of `Inter` is (are) satisfied. Most notably, we can support code that will be written in the future and implements `Inter`.

---

**Adendum**

I wrote this answer in 2015. While being overall satisfied with the answer, I always thought that something was missing and I think I finally know what it was. The following is not necessary to understand the answer, but is meant to spark interest in the reader, as well as provide some resources for further self-education.

In literature, this approach is known as [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and belongs to the [**SOLID**-principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). There is a [nice talk from uncle Bob on YouTube (the interesting bit is about 15 minutes long)](https://youtu.be/TMuno5RZNeE?t=37m43s) showing how polymorphism and interfaces can be used to let the compile-time dependency point against the flow of control (viewer's discretion is advised, uncle Bob will mildly rant about Java). This, in return, means that the high level implementation does not need to know about lower level implementations when they are segretaget through interfaces. Thus lower levels can be swapped at will, as we have shown above.

Comment: +1 Inversión of control comes to the rescue. This is the best decoupling and inversion of control relation I've ever seen. And I've read books about this topics.

Comment: But doesn't class A now depend on the interface? You just decoupled it from B and coupled it to the interface right? How is this better?

Comment: Any developer can implement the interface and inject it via Inversion of control without needing to modify the above code. It is true that `A`depends on `Inter` and thus changes to `Inter` may break all code implementing `Inter`. This is why interfaces should be designed carefully. There are some possibilities to add methods to an interface later on, e.g. through [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Answer (score 5):

Imagine that the functionality of `B` is to write a log to some database. The class `B` depends on the functionality of the class `DB` and provides some interface for its logging functionality to other classes.

Class `A` needs the logging functionality of `B`, but is does not care, where the log is written to. It does not care for `DB`, but since it depends on `B`, it also depends on `DB`. This is not very desirable.

So what you can do, is to split the class `B` into two classes: An abstract class `L` describing the logging functionality (and not depending on `DB`), and the implementation depending on `DB`.

Then you can decouple the class `A` from `B`, because now `A` will only depend on `L`. `B` now also depends on `L`, that is why it is called dependency inversion, because `B` provides the functionality offered in `L`.

Since `A` now depends on just a lean `L`, you can easily use it with other logging mechanism, not depending on `DB`. E.g. you can create a simple console based logger, implementing the interface defined in `L`.

But since now `A` does not depend on `B` but (in sources) only on the abstract interface `L` at run time it has to be set up to use some specific implementation of `L` (`B` for instance). So there needs to be somebody else that tells `A` to use `B` (or something else) during the runtime. And that is called *inversion of control*, because before `A` decided to use `B`, but now somebody else (e.g. a container) tells `A` to use `B` during the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The situation you describe removes the dependence that class A has on the specific implementation of class B and replaces it with an interface. Now class A can accept any object that is of a type that implements the interface, instead of only accepting class B. The design retains the same functionality because class B is made to implement that interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is where DI (Dependency Injection) frameworks really shine.

When you are building interfaces, you are actually building out contracts for implementation. Your calling services will only interact with the contract and the promise that a service interface will always provide the methods that it has specified.

For example...

Your `ServiceA` will build their logic around `ServiceB`'s interface and does not have to worry about what happens under `ServiceB`'s hood.

This allows you to create multiple implementations of `ServiceB` without having to change any logic in `ServiceA`.

For the sake of example

```
interface ServiceB { void doMethod() }
```

You can interact with ServiceB in ServiceA without knowing what goes under the hood of ServiceB.

```
class ServiceAImpl {

    private final ServiceB serviceB;
    
    public ServiceAImpl(ServiceBImpl serviceBImpl) {
        this.serviceB = serviceBImpl
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        serviceB.doMethod(); // calls ServiceB interface method.
    }

}
```

Now because you have built `ServiceA` using the contract specified in `ServiceB`, you are able to change out the implementation as you please.

You can mock the service, create different connection logic to different databases, create different runtime logic. All of these can change and will not at all affect the way `ServiceA` interacts with `ServiceB`.

Thus, loose coupling is achieved with IoC (Inversion of Control). You now have a modular and focused codebase.