# What is the use of Abstraction?

Tags: java, abstraction

I'm struggling to understand the overall use of Abstraction in Java.

I have been working off an example in this link: https://javatutorial.net/java-abstraction-example
I understand the implementation of it but I don't understand why its even necessary. Why is their a calculateSalary method made in the Employee class if they are just going to made again in the 2 subclasses?

Comment: As said in that link `Abstraction is a process of hiding the implementation details from the user` So `calculateSalary()` abstract function is defined in abstract `super class` so that it's `sub class` (which is extending Employee abstract class) could defined as per their `algorithm/calculation` and these `algorithm/calculation` will be hidden from other `entities/user`

Comment: All good texts on object-oriented programming and design talk about abstraction. Which ones have you studied?

Comment: @VaradMondkar the benefit of abstraction is not some kind of hiding (which implies some sort of of (false) secrecy). The real benefit is less coupling and, in return, less friction. I recommend to watch [this youtube snippet of Uncle Bob talking about polymorphism and decoupling (the relevant part is about 15 minutes long)](https://youtu.be/TMuno5RZNeE?t=37m43s).

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you for correcting and sharing the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall use of abstraction is decoupling. To work with an `Employee`, one does not need to know the implementation, only the interface and its contracts. This is, for example, used for [`Collections.sort(List<T> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)): the programmers of `Collections.sort(...)` did not need to know the implementation of a specific list in order to sort it. This provides the benefit that the implementation support future code that conforms to the [`List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784215/what-does-decoupling-two-classes-at-the-interface-level-mean) is related in that respect (#selfPromotion). Less coupling leads to less friction and overall less fragile code.

That said, the example you provided is a poor one since it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): It is not the responsibility of an `Employee` instance to calculate the salary. For this, we should have a separate object that calculates the salary, based on an `Employee`-instance and some hours worked. Internally, this Uber-calculator could use a [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), which hold one `Calculator` per `Employee`-Implementation, decoupling the `Employee` from how their salary is calculated. This provides the added benefit of extensibility and flexibility: if the way a salary is calculated changes (e.g. maybe the company switches policy so that each `FullTimeEmployee` earns the same salary, or maybe the company wants to calculate the salary on a by-week instead of a by-month basis), other services using the `FullTimeEmployee` say unaffected).

Comment: Perfectly explained